# SQL standards-compliant way to compare a parameter to a field or check if both are null

Tags: sql, jdbc

I was making a JDBC query like `SELECT id FROM objects WHERE field = ?`, but I realized it fails when the parameter value I pass in with `preparedStatement.setString()` is `null`. *I understand why*, but is there an elegant solution where I don't have to resort to twp parameters like `SELECT id FROM objects WHERE field = ? OR COALESCE(field, ?) is NULL`? Some dialects support `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, but not all. If I were using Spring's JDBC library I'd use a named parameter.

Comment: Your logic is a standard way.  I would write it as:  `field = ? or field is null and ? is null`.

Comment: AFAIK `IS DISTINCT FROM` is in the SQL standard, but I don't know many systems implement it (I know PostgreSQL and Firebird do).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel SQLite, Oracle, and SQL Sever, (among others), [don't seem to](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/09/21/the-is-distinct-from-predicate/), but you seem to be right that it's in SQL-1999.